# Oracle: What's the difference between NULL and <null>?

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried looking for the answer in Google, but didn't find any results, probably because of the angle brackets. I know what `NULL` means, but what is the purpose of `<null>`?

Comment: You'll need to provide some context - how is `<null>` being used in your system?

Comment: @StephanLechner is right. `<null>` is printed out for some query results in SQLTools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<null>` is not part of oracle syntax, it is probably used by your IDE or your console for printing out null values in query results. 
The only valid representation of a null value actually is `NULL`. Try it out:

```
-- OK:
select NULL from dual   

-- Syntax error:
select <null> from dual

-- Syntax OK, but not a null value:
select '<null>' from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql `null` is treated as an unknown value, and you can represent it as `null`, but not `<null>`, 
`<null>` is considered as a string, and if you give `<null>` without single quotes, it will give you **missing expression** error, as it has `<` & `>` in it commonly used relational operators.

So, `<null>` and `null` has no relation.

Some queries to play-around to improve your understanding,

```
select null col from dual; -- Gives 1 row.

select <null> col from dual; -- Missing expression Error

select * from (select 'null' col from dual) where col is null; -- Gives no records 

select * from (select '<null>' col from dual) where col is null; -- Gives no records

select * from (select null col from dual) where col is null; -- Returns 1 row
```

Bonus tip: In stackoverflow you cannot type/display `<null>` not as a code sample :). Observed while answering this question.